# Achieve 60Hz on my AOC U3477PQU 34" Ultrawide Monitor with Macbook Pro 15" (Late 2013)

Tags: macbook-pro, display, hdmi, displayport

I bought an AOC U3477PQU 34" Ultrawide Monitor and I am trying to achieve a higher refresh rate.

I connected my monitor to my Macbook Pro 15" Late 2013 with Intel Iris Pro 1536 MB graphics card via HDMI directly and via Mini DisplayPort to HDMI adapter and everything works fine but I have a refresh rate of 30Hz. This is quite annoying as I can see the delay even when I move my mouse cursor.

Is there any way I can get a higher refresh rate? Using an Mini Displayport to Displayport cable will solve the problem?

Thanks in advance for your help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just bought an [Mini Displayport to Displayport](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01DKHAREI) cable (4K) and now I am on 3440x1400 with 60Hz.

Comment: These monitors only support 60Hz on the DisplayPort input as you have discovered - Makes the HDMI input useless for me personally which is a shame